# Making html and body stretch to 100% height and more if the page scrolls

Tags: html, css

I want to make my `<html>` and `<body>` tags be the entire height of the viewport if the page isn't tall enough to warrant scrolling, or the entire height of the web page if it does.

At the moment I'm using this CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Which works a treat if the web page isn't tall enough for the user to scroll, however on a long webpage it only goes to the height of the viewport on the users browser. I also tried:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

but that just seems to have the same effect as having no `height` declaration at all.

Comment: I guess you're doing that because you want a footer that will always be at the bottom of the page? If so, just [google "sticky footer"](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=html+sticky+footer).

Comment: Nope, I just have a sidebar and content div which is meant to be 100% of the page height, but since I have to add `height: 100%` to make it the entire height of the users viewport, it also cuts off when the user scrolls.

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like your goal is for the body to

- always cover the screen (with minimal or no content)
- be able to stretch (if there is a ton of content)

if that's the case the following snippet should help

```
/* this looks like it should work

       html, body{
         min-height: 100%;
       }

    but this ↓ does the trick */

html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go. A good reference could be found [here](https://codepen.io/absolutholz/post/html-and-body-element-height-100)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

That should set the height of the elements to the viewport and if they go beyond, it will have a scrollbar, here is an example:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/jBaPYB

Answer (score 1):

A starting point:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

(or add a container div with an ID, etc if you have issues with some browsers.)

EDIT:  Adding full code example below:

```
<body>
    <aside>Sidebar</aside>
    <div id="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  font-size: 2em
}

aside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the html and body tags are still only as high as the users viewport.

Comment: Please see my clarification with a nested div, or maybe clarify what you are trying to do, as it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
div {
 min-height: 100%;
}
```

This is the solution for Making html and body stretch to 100% height and more if the page scrolls

Answer (score 0):

```
html
{
  height: 100%;
}
body
{
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

using max-height in body element will wrap the content within the viewable size of page and remove the scrolling or extra whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to specify the `overflow` attribute for the particular div. It will make sure your content is shown even when page is scrolled or content is more.

```
div {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```