# Making the height of a div 100% of the view-port height or the entire height of the page

Tags: html, css

If you take a look at this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbpZ/

You can see that both the `sidebar` and `content` elements stretch to the bottom of the view-port. This is what I want.

However, when given some content that stretches the page and requires the user to scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/p6qGg/

The `sidebar` and `content` divs cut off at the bottom of the view-port. I know why this happens, because `100%` refers to the entire height of the parent element which in this case is the view-port, but when I change the markup to have a wrapper div surrounding the two elements and have `min-height: 100%` this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6k9/

Similarly, if the content is no longer long enough to not fit the view-port, the `sidebar` and `content` divs act as if they have no height assigned at all: http://jsfiddle.net/xsHHv/

So my question is how can I have the `sidebar` and `content` divs be the height of the view-port if the content doesn't stretch off the page, or have them the height of the content if it does?

Comment: Hey you've got 3 open questions, apparently about the same thing, could you combine, close, or update these into one?  Really muddies up the site:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151663/making-html-and-body-stretch-to-100-height-and-more-if-the-page-scrolls) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164416/div-cuts-off-at-bottom-of-view-port-when-it-should-stretch-to-the-hight-of-the-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to give your elements a huge `padding-bottom`, with a corresponding negative `margin-bottom`:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar, #content {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 999em;
    margin-bottom: -999em;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6k9/4/

Comment: Or to use javascript to set the sidebar height equal to that of the content. I do like this one better.

Comment: The `padding-bottom` makes the sidebar really long. But then the same amount is 'cut off' with a negative `margin-bottom`. So, in theory, you would be doing nothing, because you extend it `999em` and then you cut it off by `999em`. BUT, it doesn't get cut off by `999em` because there's a `<section>` with more content next to it, pushing the document down. It's hard to explain it. You can go to the fiddle and remove `#content`, and you'll see that the sidebar looks 'normal' because of what I tried to explain.

Comment: Unfortunately this only half works. If you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6k9/2/ you can see that the sidebar and content divs don't stretch to the bottom of the page if the content doesn't take up more space than the viewport.

Comment: That's true, and it's because you still need all those height-related properties. I had just taken them out for brevity. See my update.