# DIV cuts off at bottom of view-port when it should stretch to the hight of the content inside it

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbpZ/5/

Here, I'm stretching the `content` div to 100% height and it's working fine. However, when I have some really tall content within the `content` div this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbpZ/2/

As you can see, the `content` div cuts off at the bottom of the viewport when I want it to carry on with the content inside it.

I know why this happens, because its parent element (html and body) are set to 100% height and it can't go more than that. To fix this I add a wrapper div and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbpZ/4/

But now there's another problem, when the content inside the `content` div isn't long enough to stretch outside of the viewport the `content` div doesn't stretch to the height of the page, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/2YbpZ/4/

So, the question is, how can I adapt this to make the `content` div always **at least** 100% height?

Comment: Do you need a non-jQuery answer?  Your tags would indicate that, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use a wrapper, but use `min-height:100%` instead of `height:100%` on your #content div.

**Note:** IE6 does not support min-height.

Comment: `min-height` not cross-browser compatible, esp. older (but still statisticatlly relevant) versions of IE.

Comment: if IE6 is a relevant version depends on what kind of site you want to build. but yes you both are right, IE6 doesnt understand it.

Comment: Coulda sworn more recent versions than 6 didn't support it. I did some poking around and it looks like at least in theory you're correct about that though, huh.

Comment: @Madbreaks Well as we both know IE is ever good for a surprise ;)

Comment: To get IE6 support just set `height: 100%` using conditional classes. IE6 treats `height` as `min-height`: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/