# how to force 100% height on a dynamic drive css fluid/fixed layout

Tags: css

[example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AMSgY/)

I am using a fluid/fixed layout. i need my fixed side to take up 100% of the room between the header and footer content.

my right column:

```
#rightcolumn{
float: left;
width: 200px; /*Width of right column in pixels*/
margin-left: -200px; /*Set left margin to -(RightColumnWidth) */
background: #FDE95E;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the height of a div 100% of the view-port height or the entire height of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162296/making-the-height-of-a-div-100-of-the-view-port-height-or-the-entire-height-of)

Comment: I wish dealing with fluid layouts was as elementary as that example but it requires a bit more complicated of a design to function properly.

Comment: You could do it fairly easily with javascript or jquery, is that not acceptable?

Comment: no, i need to use css and html only. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can do it with css "display: table" and "table-cell". Here's a copy of the [fiddle I got working](http://jsfiddle.net/DrCord/AMSgY/2/), but what I did was nest your #rightcolumn into the #contentwrapper div and then modify the css as so:

```
#contentwrapper{ display: table; }
#rightcolumn{ display: table-cell; }
#contentcolumn{ display: table-cell; }
```

also "#rightcolumn" - remove "float: left;" property