# div sync height to its peer on right

Tags: css

[image]I have a container div with three child divs. see attached.

the center div can dynamically stretch in height. what I want is if the container div would stretch with the center div, then the left div will stretch to fit the new container div, and therefore stay in sync with the center div.

any one knows a pure css way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the height of a div 100% of the view-port height or the entire height of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162296/making-the-height-of-a-div-100-of-the-view-port-height-or-the-entire-height-of)

Comment: no. viewport uses .html { height:100% } and let the content adjust to the browser. Here the center panel stretches during use, so the browser needs to adjust to the center panel instead.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually adjust the height of the column, but the only non-javascript way to achieve this effect without actual content pushing the height down is using faux columns.  You apply a background image to the parent element that mimics the column.  Doesn't apply as well to responsive design, but the good folks at A List Apart do a better job of explaining the method here http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: don't think this works for me. My left hand side box has a border at the bottom. so it will prob have to be javascript.

Answer (score 0):

yes that makes sense if you have a bottom-border.  Let us know if you need help with the javascript.  There will be no pure CSS way to accomplish this though.  You have to find the height of the center div with javascript, and tell your left div to be the same height.